# Регулярное выражение в htaccess не пройдет никак

Tags: php, .htaccess

Делаю удобочитаемый вид страниц

```
site.ws/odin/dwa/three
```

передаю в htaccess скрипту данные

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/([-\w]+)/(\w+)/(\w+)?$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4
```

Не смотря на знания регулярок, не могу сделать так, чтобы проходили символы "." и "-", как это реализовать?

Comment: в скобках квадратных точку экранировать не надо, а минус ставится последним, если вы про это

Comment: ничего не работает

Comment: вы приведите пример ссылки которая не проходит, чтобы было о чем говорить. В вашей регулярке наличие завершающего `/` в третьей группе обязательно, но его нет в приведенной ссылке